# rails - validating a model in a belongs_to relationship - presence of model vs. model_id

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I've been reading around for a few hours now, trying to understand the right approach.

I have a `User` model and a `Origin` model.
The relationship between them is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :origin, dependent: :destroy  

class Origin < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

I am setting up tests as rails best practices suggest and I've come to a problem when essentially wanting to validate the Origin's association with the User. I don't want to use `validates_associated` because I don't want to check User validity when I create/manipulate its Origin. All I care to achieve is to make sure the Origin is correctly associated with an existing (in the DB) User.

I want these tests to pass:

```
test "user should be present" do
    assert @origin.user
end

test "user id should be present" do
    assert @origin.user_id
end

test "nil user id is invalid" do
    @origin.user_id = nil
    assert_not @origin.valid?
end
```

I'd think rails would already have a validator for this common relationship, checking that the User exists and the user_id belongs to this User.

I tried a few combinations with
 `validates :user, presence: true` , `validates :user_id, presence: true`
but none give me what I'm looking for.
Do I have to write a custom validation method to achieve this?